# Activity and Fragment concurrency

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, concurrency, android-asynctask

According to the Api activity and fragment work on the same ui thread. Is there any concurrency issue in the following two situtations (pseudocode)?

1. Activity starts a fragment in onCreate and intializes an object, which is accessible from fragment.

   ```
   //Object
   class Object{
        String name = "test";
        int age = 20;
   }

   //Activity onCreate
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       startFragment();
       setActivityObject();
   }

   //Fragment onCreateView
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   getActivityObject();
   return view;
   ```

   }

According to [android developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) onCreateView can be finished before on Activity has finished its onCreate (that's why we call onActivityCreated). 1)Is it possible for the fragment to display the object before Activity has initialized it? 2)Is it possible, for the Activity to have edited the name to test2 and then fragment calls getActivityObject() before edits the age to age = 10?Then fragment  will get an invalid state object with name ="test2" and age=20, instead of name="test2" and age=10. Do synchronized setters/getters needed for this situation?

2. In the above example, the activity sets the object via an asyncTask. Do the previous 2 scenarios have the same problems?

I have isolated this scenario from my project. In some other cases i use callbacks to inform fragments for the data state. I can't use it here because the Activity replaces the fragments so a fragment may have its data ready in onCreateView and activity will never trigger the callback in that situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When thinking about synchronization in your scenarios you need to differentiate between threads synchronization as opposed to simply understanding the order of callbacks. As long as you don't use threads, async tasks, timers etc - you have no thread issues. But you still need to know what happens when to avoid problems.

Assuming the fragment is part of the Activity's xml layout, that fragment's onCreateView() will be called *before* the Activity's onCreate() method is finished. This is simply because the code that initializes the fragments (and thus eventually calls the fragments' onCreateView()) is part of the activity's setContentView() method which is called in onCreate(). It's easy to see with logs at the beginning and end of these methods. You get something like this:

```
Activity.onCreate start
Activity calling setContentView...
Fragment.onCreateView start
Fragment.onCreateView end
Activity setContentView done
Activity.onCreate end
```

The ordering is constant and guaranteed. In other words, if you initializes the object inside the activity's onCreate() method, but *before* calling setContentView(), the fragment can freely access the object. You are also 100% safe from inconsistent object state because all those callbacks indeed run on the same thread. There's simply no risk of the activity and fragment working on the object simultaneously.

As to your second question - Once you employ a different thread to initialize the object you can no longer guarantee anything. You can't tell whether the initialization is done. Then you do need to start thinking about concurrency - synchronize your getters/setters, use callbacks to notify to the fragment when it's done, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. i will accept the answer. One more thing. In the second situation isn't the async task responsible to post the data in ui thread. If i don't have sync problems in 1 scenario, i shouldn't have problems in scenario 2 either. am i right?

Comment: The post will be on the UI thread, it's just that you don't know when it happens. You prevent data corruption (object in mid-edit), but you don't know the timing. Say this async task loads data to be posted in a TextView - in the post callback you don't know if onCreateView() is done, so you don't know if the TextView is available yet. Basically you could just start the async task after finishing with the UI for this simple scenario, but some cases are more complicated. Locking isn't needed as there are no parallel threads, but some synchronization code might still be needed.